# Easy bipolar motor control?

Tags: arduino-uno, programming, motor, electronics, electricity

Is here some easy way to control bipolar motor
 without using any other external devices, drivers or shields? I have small motor from CD-ROM so I expect it's low voltage. By control I mean just turning clockwise  and anti-clockwise and speed. I'm looking for easy to make circuit not just direct control from Arduino.

Comment: It depends on the motor but is quite unlikely for most motors due to the limited current (and voltage) the Arduino's GPIO pins can provide.

Comment: I have 4 wire motor

Comment: Please give us more details.  It will attract better answers.

Comment: Welcome to Arduino SE.  Be sure to take the tour to see how things work here:  https://arduino.stackexchange.com/Tour

Comment: Please edit your question (click the edit button, etc) and tell what you mean by *control* – ie, turning the motor on/off, or changing direction or speed, etc.  Also list motor model number or specs  – a low-voltage micromotor might not need external parts, but most motors will.  If you improve the question people may vote it up.

Answer (score 1):

No. You cannot directly drive any bare motor directly from an Arduino without any external components. To do so will damage the Arduino.

You need a motor driver (or at least some transistors and diodes etc) to control the motor.

Answer (score 1):

Taking a guess here, the current this motor requires will be exceeding the safe operation limits of the Arduino's GPIO pins. Furthermore without a [flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) the voltage spike across the motor (an inductive load) when the current is reduced/switched off might kill the GPIO pin.

You will need a motor driver or transistor with flyback diodes to operate it.

[This](http://www.instructables.com/id/Run-A-CDROM-Brushless-Motor-With-Arduino/) is a nice tutorial that has it sorted out for a CD ROM brushless motor.

Comment: It's not just about the current - back EMF from the motor's coils will do nasty things to the Arduino.